# How to return distinct on first column only and still return the other 4

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is the sql query I'm trying to get to work...

```
SELECT distinct
r.Heat
,c.ctemp
,s.ShiftIdent
,r.ChargeSeq
,s.rollLocSeq
FROM (NYS1ShiftCut s inner join NYS1CharpyOrders c on c.CharpyOrderID = s.CharpyID)
join NYS1Reheat r on r.LocSeq = s.RollLocSeq 
where c.CTemp < +40 
order by s.rollLocSeq desc
```

I need just the "r.heat" to be the distinct return, with the remaining columns populated with whatever they contain. The c.ctemp and s.shiftident could easily contain duplicate info, the r.chargeseq and s.rollLocseq will be unique returns.

I've tried a couple of sub-queries to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here are the retuned columns...

```
439799  -04 05/22/15154D    126 542949330

439799  -04 05/22/15154D    124 542949310

439799  -04 05/22/15154D    123 542949300

439799  -04 05/22/15154D    122 542949290

439799  -04 05/22/15154D    121 542949280

439797  -04 05/22/15154D    117 542949240

439797  -04 05/22/15154D    116 542949230
```

Comment: What if the other three are different for the same value of `r.Heat`?  Which value(s) do you want?  Max? Min? Average?  Pick one at random?

Comment: Here is a small sample of the returned info as it is now...                 439799 -04 05/22/15154D 126 542949330
439799 -04 05/22/15154D 124 542949310
439799 -04 05/22/15154D 123 542949300
439799 -04 05/22/15154D 122 542949290
439799 -04 05/22/15154D 121 542949280
439799 -04 05/22/15154D 120 542949270
439799 -04 05/22/15154D 119 542949260
439799 -04 05/22/15154D 118 542949250
439797 -04 05/22/15154D 117 542949240
439797 -04 05/22/15154D 116 542949230

Comment: All the other items are needed but are irrelevant to the "sort" sequence.

Comment: @Obfuscated - What is the expected output for the given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no construct in SQL Server to give you an arbitrary value for non-grouped columns.  Either you need to group by those columns or use some sore of aggregate function.

If the values of the other columns are "irrelevant" as you indicate in your comments, then you can use `MIN` to pick a value for each column:

```
SELECT distinct
r.Heat
,MIN(c.ctemp)
,MIN(s.ShiftIdent)
,MIN(r.ChargeSeq)
,MIN(s.rollLocSeq)
FROM (NYS1ShiftCut s inner join NYS1CharpyOrders c on c.CharpyOrderID = s.CharpyID)
join NYS1Reheat r on r.LocSeq = s.RollLocSeq 
where c.CTemp < +40 
GROUP BY r.Heat
order by s.rollLocSeq desc
```

The choice of `MIN` is arbitrary, is could also be `MAX` or `AVG` (with the caveat that `AVG` may give you values that aren't in the source data if they are not all equal.

Comment: I found this one to be the "best" result for my app. I was thinking that by using MIN that it would give me falsely, too few returns, then realized that that was exactly what I was wanting.  Thank you D Stanley for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
How about Something like the following:
SELECT
r.Heat
,c.ctemp
,s.ShiftIdent
,r.ChargeSeq
,s.rollLocSeq
FROM (NYS1ShiftCut s inner join NYS1CharpyOrders c on c.CharpyOrderID = s.CharpyID)
join NYS1Reheat r on r.LocSeq = s.RollLocSeq 
where c.CTemp < +40 
AND r.heat IN (SELECT DISTINCT r.HEAT FROM NYS1ShiftCut s inner join NYS1CharpyOrders c on c.CharpyOrderID = s.CharpyID)
join NYS1Reheat r on r.LocSeq = s.RollLocSeq) 
order by s.rollLocSeq desc
```

Comment: I've tried grouping but continue to get errors, perhaps a small example?

Comment: Group By will not work. I have edited the query above. Please check.